# Is it safe to return a passed-in temporary value and read from it in the same statement?

Tags: c++, scope, undefined-behavior

I just wrote this without thinking too hard about it. It seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if it's strictly safe.

```
class Foo
{
    struct Buffer
    {
        char data [sizeof ("output will look like this XXXX YYYY ZZZZ")];
    };

    const char * print (const char * format = DEFUALT_FORMAT, Buffer && buf = Buffer ())
    {
        sort_of_sprintf_thing (format, buf .data, sizeof (buf.data), ...);
        return buf .data;
    }
};

std :: cout << Foo () .print ();
```

So I *think* the semantics are that the temporary Buffer will remain in existence until the whole `cout` statement completes. Is that right, or will it go out of scope before then, in which case this is UB?

Comment: This one's safe, but dangerous. You'd be better off returning `Buffer` by value from `print`, and creating an overload `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Buffer^)`.

Comment: @Angew `^`? [filler text here]

Comment: @Angew "safe but dangerous"... Indeed :D

Comment: @immibis Typo. Should have been `&`, naturally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your code is well-defined.

> #### [class.temporary]
>
> 3 - [...] Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. [...]
>
> #### [intro.execution]
>
> 11 - *[ Note:* The evaluation of a full-expression can include the evaluation of subexpressions that are not lexically
> part of the full-expression. For example, subexpressions involved in evaluating default arguments (8.3.6) are
> considered to be created in the expression that calls the function, not the expression that deﬁnes the default
> argument. *— end note ]*

That doesn't mean it's particularly *good*, though - it would be far too easy to bind the result of `Foo().print()` to a `char const*` variable, which would on the next full-expression become a dangling pointer.

Comment: I'm bad at the lawyer speak in the standard documents.  Does this mean the temporary actually lasts longer than its function's stack?  In the case of `printf(Foo().print())`, does the temporary from `Foo::print()` last long enough for the `printf`?  (This is probably identical to the OP, but `ostream& operator<<` confuses the crap out of me when I'm trying to figure out what stack depth I'm at.)

Comment: @Aggieboy yes, that's right - the lifetime of the temporary is the extent of the calling expression, as if the default argument were cut-and-pasted into the call site.

Comment: @Aggieboy: It will work for that use case, but the function is prone to misuse and errors. The whole design seems awkward... why does the function optionally take the buffer?  There is something smelly in that interface

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas  I disagree.  The function may need a certain work-space to do its job, and if you already have a scratch work-space then you can provide it.  Otherwise, it will create its own.

To return a pointer to the aforementioned workspace after the function completes, though, is probably a bit weird.

Comment: @Aggieboy: the returning of the pointer to a workspace that might no longer exist is what makes this wrong. You can conceive two different overloads, one using a user-provided buffer and another that is simpler and doesn't, but the semantics need to be different, you have to ensure that the object's lifetime is well documented and usable. Conflating both interfaces can lead to issues like the leaking of the pointer to an already destroyed object in the case of `auto x = Foo().print();`

Comment: @Aggieboy: that is why this is a code-smell, the design you got into is *fragile* at best (I consider it broken, but am willing to accept *fragile* as a middle ground). If you want to overload, the cost is not that huge, you need one overload where the user provides the buffer and a different one where they don't, you need to ensure that you provide a mechanism for the user to release the resources for the second overload... The two overloads are inherently very different.

Answer (score 5):

The code is bad, the problem being not on the calling site, but rather on the `print` function. You are taking an *rvalue* (only thing that will bind to an *rvalue-reference*) and returning a pointer to its internals which is a recipe for Undefined Behavior (if the user dereferences the `const char*` returned).

In the particular example that you have, the `Foo()` temporary will live long enough, but this code is prone to clients storing the `const char*` beyond the full expression and causing undefined behavior.